# Скрытие некоторых элементов Google Maps

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

Всем привет.

Возможно, кто-то знает можно ли убрать как-то верхнее меню в карте с нанесенным треком.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В живую можно увидеть здесь - https://www.apex-mountain.ru/trekking-k-everestu/

В интернете нашел вариант карты с треком без этого меню, но без понятия как воплотить в жизнь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь !

Comment: Когда создаёте объект map в JS, добавьте свойство disableDefaultUI: false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в style.css

```
.i4ewOd-pzNkMb-haAclf {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, данный вариант не сработал.

Нашел еще один в интернете:

```css
.container-iframe{
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #555;   
}
.container-iframe > iframe{  
  border: none;  
  margin-top: -46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-iframe">
<iframe src="ссылка на карту" width="100%" height="420"></iframe>
</div>
```

Но он тоже не сработал.

И все-таки нашел рабочий вариант:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height: 300px;">
  <iframe 
     src="ссылка на карту"
     width="100%"
     height="600"
     frameborder="0"
     style="border:0; margin-top: -150px;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

В любом случае спасибо за помощь.